# resultado de una consulta en diferentes divs separados

Tags: php, mysql, css, bootstrap, tablas

necesito acomodar los valores de los id que surge de una consulta mysql,pero resulta que los tengo que acomodar en diferentes divs, osea que para cada div le corresponde un id. ya logre conseguir los ids con sus valores

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';

$sql = "SELECT id, nombre_producto, precio, descripcion FROM productos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $row["id"];
  $row["nombre_producto"];
  $row["precio"];
  $row["descripcion"];
  
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

pero me falta acomodar cada id en dicho div, no se que puedo hacer, o cual seria el procedimiento para que cada id quede dentro de cada div osea quedando asi

```
<div> id 1 de la consulta sql
</div>
<div> id  2 de la consulta sql
</div>
<div> id 3 de la consulta sql
</div>
```

Agradezco mucho su paciencia,Gracias

Comment: Este problema quedo resuelto haciendo uso de if junto con los operadores de comparacion con ids.
quedando de esta forma, muchas gracias por su atencion

Answer (score -1):

```
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo("<div>".$row["id"]."</div>"); //así printas en pantalla cada ID en un DIV independiente.
$row["nombre_producto"];
$row["precio"];
$row["descripcion"];

}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Me imprime asi 666555444 cuando yo solo quiero que me imprima de esta forma 654

Comment: Eso ya es problema de la query, seguro que devuelve solo 3 registros? Según lo que comentas, el limit 3 no esta funcionando, esta devolviendo triplicado cada registro. (con lo que puedo ver es lo único que puedo deducir). Puedes hacer la prueba de solo dejar 3 registros en esa tabla, y probar ese mismo código.